# 'Present' terminal window on shell/executable command?

Tags: terminal, x11, xfce, window-management, xfce4-terminal

Currently using Xfce and xfce4-terminal, but suggestions involving other Linux-based systems may still be helpful.

I start a longish-running program in a terminal window, then alt-tab away and do other work. Is there a way to have a program in that session request that its window be marked 'Urgent' and/or 'Presented' to the user? When I'm writing a graphical program, say using GTK2, I can do that easily enough; it ought to be theoretically possible, but I don't know of a way to do it.

Comment: A combination of inotify, [yad](http://sourceforge.net/projects/yad-dialog/) and writing a file to disk upon termination/"interesting" milestones.

Comment: I think most people use `xdotool` for this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `wmctrl` to tell the window manager to activate it (raise it and give it focus):

```
wmctrl -ia "$WINDOWID"
```

Comment: Thank you, that's perfect! I wasn't aware of the environment variable, and that's beautifully simple. `alias present='wmctrl -ia $WINDOWID'` in .bashrc and all is as it should be!

Answer (score 0):

Try raising the bell:

```
printf '\a'
```

This doesn't work with all terminal emulators; I don't know about xfce4-terminal. In xterm, it's a mode (the `bellIsUrgent` and `popOnBell` resources) that can be turned on and off with [control sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#ctlseqs_ms), so try turning it on:

```
printf '\e[?1042;1043h\a'
```

Comment: The bell on its own didn't work, so I tried the other; but it seems to be an unrecognized escape code. Are those actual 0x3F question marks?

Comment: Ah, but thanks to that search term, I did find this: http://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=6573 So I guess it's not possible, at least with that terminal emulator.